# Android OpenGL ES rotating screen

Tags: opengl-es

I use Gaussian blur to achieve the lighting effect.

On android, after rotating the screen, the first half of the screen is normal, and the second half of the screen is jagged.

This problem has also appeared on some iOS phones.

I don't know what the problem is.

I used fbo, texture buffering, depth buffering, and stencil buffering, and I recreated them with new dimensions each time I rotated the screen.

Ask what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Try modifying your fragment shader to use highp instead of mediump. Mediump (the default) is often not high enough for UV coordinates on full-screen effects.

Comment: @Columbo I use the lowest precision, modify it to high precision, the problem is solved, thank you very much. The effect of precision on the display effect is so great.